# 2 tipos de produtos em uma mesma view

Tags: python, aplicação-web, django

Como eu poderia listar 2 tipos de produtos na *index* (Pizzas e Bebidas)  definindo um *order by* e dividindo em `divs` diferentes (`div` das bebidas, `div` das pizzas), segue o que eu tenho:

```
class IndexListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'inicio.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'
    paginate_by = 5
```

Gostaria de uma explicação de qual seria a melhor maneira de se fazer isso.

Answer (score 0):

A "Melhor maneira de se fazer isso" é um pouco subjetivo, depende, essencialmente, do contexto. Vamos criar uma pequena aplicação para tentar resolver o problema, vou relatar os passos (meu ambiente é Linux):

1) Crie um projeto chamado pizza, e uma app chamada core:

```
$ django-admin startproject pizza
$ cd pizza
$ ./manage.py startapp core
```

2) Edite o arquivo models em core (core/models.py) e faça-o ficar com o seguinte conteudo:

```
from django.db import models

class Pizza(models.Model):
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    descricao = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    preco = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='preço',decimal_places=2, max_digits=9)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.descricao

class Bebida(models.Model):
    codigo = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    descricao = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    preco = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='preço', decimal_places=2, max_digits=9)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.descricao
```

3) Edit core/views.py:

```
from .models import Pizza, Bebida
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class IndexView(ListView):
    template_name = 'core/index.html'
    model = Pizza

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['bebidas'] = Bebida.objects.all()

        return context
```

4) Edit pizza/url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from core.views import IndexView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

]
```

5) Edit core/templates/core/index.html

```
<div id = "pizzas">
  <ul>
    {% for objl in object_list %}
       <li>{{ objl}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>


<div id = "bebida">
  <ul>
    {% for b in bebidas %}
       <li>{{ b }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

6) Edit core/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Pizza, Bebida

admin.site.register(Pizza)
admin.site.register(Bebida)
```

7) Rode o projeto e, através do admin, adicione alguns intens em pizza e em bebida.

8) Aponte o browse para a pagina index e vc verá as pizzas e as bebidas que vc incluiu, em suas respectivas divs.